# Обновить фильтрацию в Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Есть таблица со значениями и пустыми строками.  Сверху есть шапка.
Мне важно чтобы пустые строки скрывались.
Фильтр применяю всё скрывается, всё супер.

Но когда данные в таблицы обновляются, фильтр автоматически не применяется и не скрывает вновь появившиеся пустые строки. Надо заходить в фильтр и снова его применить.
Как сделать чтобы фильтр автоматом отрабатывал?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно какое-то действие, чтобы оно послужило триггером для обновления фильтров. Допустим, это загрузка таблицы. Тогда Вам нужен триггер [onOpen(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene), который запускается при открытии Гугл Таблицы (перезагрузка страницы тоже считается ее открытием).
А уже внутри триггера нужно написать функцию обновления фильтра. Допустим по такому алгоритму:

1. Получаем [фильтр](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getFilter()) на нужной нам странице.
2. Можно [удалить](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#remove()) этот фильтр и установить [новый](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createFilter()) с нужными Вам параметрами и диапазоном.
3. Профит :)